# ava RabbitMQ client (amqp-client-3.6.5.jar) is blocking indefinitely on "Channel.Open" command

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Integration AMQP 4.1.2, Spring Rabbit 1.4.3, Spring Amqp 1.4.3, amqp-client-3.6.5.jar to publish messages to RabbitMQ server 3.5.3
As part of negative testing, I am sending messages to Non Existing Exchange. 
I have a negative acknowledgement handler configured using Spring Integration Amqp. This negative acknowledgement handler got invoked with the failed message and even this message contains the reason for negative acknowledgement. 
Everything is perfect up to here.

I need to Retry the failed message again as part of requirement. So the negative acknowledgement handler retires to publish the same message again.
At this time, when the Java RabbitMQ client (amqp-client-3.6.5.jar) trying to issue the command "Channel.Open" to the RabbitMQ server.
But this call getting blocked indefinitely (AMQP Connection thread is indefinitely waiting on the Object BlockingValueOrException which is responsible to notify) 
and the Java client is indefinitely waiting for the response to the command "Channel.Open". But I could see a new channel got created in RabbitMQ server using the admin console.

Why my "Channel.Open" call getting blocked?  Is RabbitMQ server failed to send response to the command "Channel.Open"?
How to check the command requests and responses passed in between Java RabbitMQ client and RabbitMQ server? Do we have any plugins that need be installed in RabbitMQ server?

Please help me in this regard. Configuration information is below.

### Spring Integration Amqp configuration that publishes messages and registers ack/nack, return handlers

```
<!-- AMQP/RMQ Publishing -->
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" exchange-name="${prism.rabbitmq.exchange}"
        routing-key-expression="headers['${prism.rabbitmq.message.header.routingKey}']" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
        mapped-request-headers="*" channel="outgoingRabbit"
        confirm-ack-channel="successfullyPublishedChannel"
        confirm-nack-channel="mailPublishingExceptionChannel"
        confirm-correlation-expression="#this" lazy-connect="false" return-channel="mailPublishingExceptionChannel"/>


<!-- AMQP client connection factory -->
    <bean id="amqpClientConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="uri"
            value="amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672" />
        <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled"
            value="true" /> 
    </bean>


    <rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory"
        host="127.0.0.1" connection-factory="amqpClientConnectionFactory"
        publisher-confirms="true" publisher-returns="true" channel-cache-size="5"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory"
        exchange="${prism.rabbitmq.exchange}" retry-template="retryTemplate" mandatory="true"/>

    <bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
        <property name="retryPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                <property name="maxAttempts" value="4" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="backOffPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
                <property name="multiplier" value="5.0" />
                <property name="maxInterval" value="60000" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

### Negative Acknowledgement Handler configuration

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="mailPublishingExceptionChannel"    ref="mailPublishingExceptionHandler" method="handleError" />
```

### Negative Acknowledgement Handler class's handle method.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("outgoingRabbit")
private MessageChannel outgoingRabbit;

@Override
public void handleError(Message<?> genMessage) {
        try {

            // Retry !!
            // Get the failed RMQ Message whose payload is JSON and has Message
            // Headers as well.

            Message failedRMQMessage = (Message) genMessage.getPayload();
            MessageBuilder rmqMessageWithRetry = MessageBuilder.withPayload(failedRMQMessage.getPayload());
            rmqMessageWithRetry.copyHeaders(failedRMQMessage.getHeaders());
            new MessagingTemplate().send(outgoingRabbit, rmqMessageWithRetry.build());  --> this call again publishes the payload


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Let me ask a question for simplification. You send to nonexistent exchange with a `returnCallback`. And looks like the last one make a loop and in the same Thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: Related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/YSpQ6TgIwpQ